# Building Jenkins job through slave machine which has more disk space

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i have a main Jenkins pipeline job which calls other multiple sub jobs during build time.

Also i have 2 Jenkins slave machines, where slave1 has 100GB space left slave2 has 30GB space left.

But during build time Jenkins is using slave2 instead of slave1 which has more space compared to slave2.

**How to configure Jenkins so that, it will use slave machine which has more space?**

Answer (score 1):

In the Jenkins pipeline you can mention where you want to run your job like below:

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
node('labelName'){
  stage('...') {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Declarative Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'agentLabaleName'
  }
  stages {
     stage('...') {
        steps {
            .....
        }
     }
  }
}
```

more information can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)

Comment: i can run jenkins job like above, But my question is how do i run in slave machines which has more disk space, every time i dont want to change the label manually,

Comment: Just mentioned the slave name in node(..) and agent { label ‘...’ } so that , jenkins will scheduled the job on the mentioned slave. If you want to pick which slave has more memory it need little bit programming